# http.post returns res.headers undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient, asp-net-core-spa-services

in my web API (asp core) 
when I post object to save in DB it return CreatAtRoute
wich is the URL or location of the object
like: http://localhost:api/photo/45

and it just return "res.headers undefined"

I am using this code 
to get url of object that recently saved in db

```
 addBankCard(bankCard: BankCard, id: string): Observable<BankCard> {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'users/' + id + '/bankcards', bankCard)
      .pipe(
        flatMap((res) => {
          const loc = (res as Response).headers.get('Location');
          return this.http.get<BankCard>(loc);
        })
      );
  }
```

and it just returns "res.headers undefined"

the API work perfectly
and I am using AllowAnyHeaders in startup class in Aspnetcore webapi

what should I do?

Comment: try ```post(this.baseUrl + 'users/' + id + '/bankcards', bankCard , {observe: 'response'})```

Comment: I want to return the bankcard object the one you said returning the observable<httprespose>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular `httpclient` return response body by default. If you can to access the entire response you need to change `observe` type in function params :

```
addBankCard(bankCard: BankCard, id: string): Observable<BankCard> {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'users/' + id + '/bankcards', bankCard,  {observe: 'response'})
      .pipe(
        flatMap((res) => {
          const loc = res.headers.get('Location');
          return this.http.get<BankCard>(loc);
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: i tried that one same result

Comment: And what if you try not to cast `res` : `(res as Response)` ?